# Tensorflow: Interpretation of Weight in Weighted Cross Entropy

Tags: tensorflow

The Tensorflow function `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits()` takes the argument `pos_weight`. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) defines `pos_weight` as *"A coefficient to use on the positive examples*." I assume this means that increasing `pos_weight` increases the loss from false positives and decreases the loss from false negatives. Or do I have that backwards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it's the other way around. Citing documentation:

> The argument `pos_weight` is used as a multiplier for the positive
>   targets.

So, assuming you have `5` positive examples in your dataset and `7` negative, if you set the `pos_weight=2`, then your loss would be as if you had `10` positive examples and `7` negative.

Assume you got all of the positive examples wrong and all negative right. Originally you would have `5` false negatives and `0` false positives. When you increase the `pos_weight`, the number of false negatives will artificially increase. Note that the loss value coming from false positives doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks. So if using a mutually exclusive classifier with more than 2 classes and 1-hot truth labels, increasing pos_weight has the effect of amplifying the losses in all cases with wrong estimates, and cases with correct estimates are unchanged (because the loss in the correct-estimate cases is zero)?

Comment: amplifying the losses in all cases with *false negatives*, but yes, I think so.