# Tensorflow Object Detection: Using new detected images to retrain model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I have searched through this forum for similar questions but was unanswered ([Updating Tensorflow Object detection model with new images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51884713/8829431)). I have managed to create my custom train model (lets name it model1). Was wondering if can i use new images that are processed by model1 to further train model1? will it improve the accuracy of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of machine learning (that is the approach you are using for object detection here) is that of **generalization**. In your case, it is the ability to recognize objects of the same type as image you used for training, in images that were not used during training.

Obviously, if you were able to use all the possible images during training, your system would be perfect (actually, it would be a simple exact image matching problem). In a more realistic setup, the more training image you are using, the higher chance you have to obtain a better object detector.

Usually, it is however more valuable to add **hard examples** to your training set. Hence, if your application allows it (in terms of computation time in particular) you can indeed add all the images that are wrongly detected in your dataset (with the correct label) and it will probably help to get a better model, able to detect the object in harder condition on new images.

However, it really depends on what you are doing. If you want to compare your system to another one, you need to use the same (training and) test images to be fair. **For benchmarking, you are not allowed to include test images in the training dataset**! When you compute the accuracy (on a validation/test dataset) to compare several settings, be sure you are fair in this comparison.

Comment: @ xiawi Thank you for your comment. i think i understand what you mean. So i guess adding wrongly detected or poorly detected dataset would be better than adding all the data.

Comment: If you have already enough "easy example", only adding hard example will probably be more valuable. It limits the training cost (in comparison to the use of all data) while helping to improve performances

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy will depend on the number of correctly classified images and not only on the total number of training images. https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/accuracy. If you consider that the new images are to be used for training (have correct labels), then you should consider re-training the model. Take a look at this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/should-a-model-be-re-trained-if-new-observations-are-available

Answer (score 1):

It might improve it but it is tricky. It would lead to overfitting. Improving the data set would actually help, but not with images detected by its own model. This kind of images are detected cause the model already performs well on them, so not much help.

What you need actually is quite the opposite. You need to teach the model to recognize the images that it didn't recognize before

Comment: @B.Kocis I think i did not explain clearly. What I mean was using new images (model1 was not train by these images) with the objects detected by model1 to further retrain model1 (or even create a new model). Will that improve model1? For example if model1 detect object A in new image with 70%. when i include this new image into retraining will the new model improve?

Comment: Sorry if i seem blur. I am still unable to understand how object detection works. I am only able to use it.

Comment: No problem. Object detection does some steps. Try to have a quick look to Faster-RCNN or just RCNN for simplicity if you have time. It basically combines a CNN Deep Learning algorithm for "image Classification" with a Region Proposals(ROI) algorithm.   I.e. it does   ROI  + Classification --> video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDPWywWRIRo&t=3944s]. Basic explanation: [https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/12/31/object-recognition-for-dummies-part-3.html#r-cnn]

Comment: @B.Kocis Would also like to ask if i want to add a few new images to further train the model (For example, the model cannot detect the objects). Would it be better to add them to the train dataset than the test dataset?

Comment: If you are using new images with detection accuracy over 70%, then I think it would actually enrich the data set and therefore it would improve the performance after training using this data set. So in my opinion yes, I think this would work. Nevertheless I would have a look at the detected objects to be sure that most of the objects are properly detected. Otherwise rise the accuracy threshold to 0.90 or so

Answer (score 1):

You can use your current model (model1) in a number of ways:

- on new images to detect bad results (hard examples) for new training
- on new images to detect good results for evaluation
- on the images in the existing dataset to detect bad images (wrong label etc.)

Some of the bad results from new images will be non-objects (adversarial) and not directly usable for training (but see this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3578#issuecomment-375267920).

Removal of bad images from the existing dataset requires retraining from scratch unless there is some funky way of "untraining" images from a model.

Eventually one would end up approaching a perfect dataset that makes best use of the capacity of the chosen model architecture, although the domain may evolve over time.

I think the reason this is not much discussed is because most researchers have to work with common datasets so they can compare their approaches (brilliant read: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5697567/).