# Multi-class weighted loss for semantic image segmentation in keras/tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

Given batched RGB images as input, shape=(batch_size, width, height, 3)

And a multiclass target represented as one-hot, shape=(batch_size, width, height, n_classes)

And a model (Unet, DeepLab) with softmax activation in last layer.

I'm looking for weighted categorical-cross-entropy loss funciton in kera/tensorflow.

The `class_weight` argument in `fit_generator` doesn't seems to work, and I didn't find the answer here or in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115.

```
def weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights):
    # weights = [0.9,0.05,0.04,0.01]
    def wcce(y_true, y_pred):
        # y_true, y_pred shape is (batch_size, width, height, n_classes)
        loos = ?...
        return loss

    return wcce
```

Comment: By multiclass target do you mean more than 1 possible outcomes are considered?

Comment: What do you mean by "outcome"? Multiclass=Different pixel value indicate different class. And you can have more than 2 classes. (2 classes=binary classification)

Comment: Multiclass classification is a different kind of classification problem where more than 1 class can be true, I got confused with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer my question:

```
def weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights):
    # weights = [0.9,0.05,0.04,0.01]
    def wcce(y_true, y_pred):
        Kweights = K.constant(weights)
        if not K.is_tensor(y_pred): y_pred = K.constant(y_pred)
        y_true = K.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * K.sum(y_true * Kweights, axis=-1)
    return wcce
```

Usage:

```
loss = weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Generalized Dice Loss. It works better than the Weighted Categorical Crossentropy in my case. My implementation is in PyTorch, however, it should be fairly easy to translate it.

```
class GeneralizedDiceLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GeneralizedDiceLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, inp, targ):
        inp = inp.contiguous().permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
        targ = targ.contiguous().permute(0, 2, 3, 1)

        w = torch.zeros((targ.shape[-1],))
        w = 1. / (torch.sum(targ, (0, 1, 2))**2 + 1e-9)

        numerator = targ * inp
        numerator = w * torch.sum(numerator, (0, 1, 2))
        numerator = torch.sum(numerator)

        denominator = targ + inp
        denominator = w * torch.sum(denominator, (0, 1, 2))
        denominator = torch.sum(denominator)

        dice = 2. * (numerator + 1e-9) / (denominator + 1e-9)

        return 1. - dice
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be similar to: [Unbalanced data and weighted cross entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560549/unbalanced-data-and-weighted-cross-entropy) which has an accepted answer.

Comment: No it's not. I'm asking about pixelwise classification.