# Categorical cross entropy with asymmetric error penalty

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a model that was adapted from Matterport's [implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) of Mask R-CNN with unbalanced data. I have modified a loss function to apply class weights to a classification loss function as [suggested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563055/8075803) using a one-hot representation of the true class, but what I would really like to do is a more general case where I can have matrix of weights to provide different penalties for the predicted class given the actual label class, as alluded to in the last paragraph of the previous answer.

```
def mrcnn_class_loss_graph(target_class_ids, pred_class_logits,
                           active_class_ids):
    """Loss for the classifier head of Mask RCNN.
    batch = 1
    num_classes = 8  
    num_rois = variable
    target_class_ids: [batch, num_rois]. Integer class IDs. Uses zero padding to fill in the array.
    pred_class_logits: [batch, num_rois, num_classes]
    active_class_ids: [batch, num_classes]. Has a value of 1 for classes that are in the dataset of 
        the image, and 0 for classes that are not in the dataset.
    """
    # During model building, Keras calls this function with target_class_ids of type float32. 
    # Unclear why. Cast it to int to get around it.
    target_class_ids = tf.cast(target_class_ids, 'int64')

    # Find predictions of classes that are not in the dataset.
    pred_class_ids = tf.argmax(input=pred_class_logits, axis=2)
    pred_active = tf.gather(active_class_ids[0], pred_class_ids)

    # penalty_matrix = tf.constant([
    #         [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.2, 1.5, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.0, 1.5, 0.8, 0.8],
    #         [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
    #         [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.0]
    #     ])

    class_weights = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]])

    one_hot = tf.one_hot(target_class_ids, depth = class_weights.shape[1], on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)
    # deduce weights for batch samples based on their true label
    weights = tf.reduce_sum(class_weights * one_hot, axis=2)
    # compute your (unweighted) softmax cross entropy loss
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=one_hot, logits=pred_class_logits)

    # apply the weights, relying on broadcasting of the multiplication
    loss = loss * weights

    # Erase losses of predictions of classes that are not in the active classes of the image.
    loss = loss * pred_active

    # Compute loss mean. Use only predictions that contribute to the loss to get a correct mean.
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=loss) / tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=pred_active)

    return loss
```

In the above code, I've commented out a potential 8x8 penalty matrix wherein the entry *j* of each row *i* corresponds to the penalty of misidentifying an object of class *i* as class *j*; the diagonal zeros represent a correct classification.

I was wondering how to correctly (and efficiently) get the weights from such a penalty matrix based on the true and predicted classes. I'm using TensorFlow 2.5 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for PyTorch:

```py
import torch

batch_size = 2
num_classes = 3
penalty_matrix = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 2], [4, 5, 0]]).long()
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')  

logits = torch.randn(batch_size, num_classes, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.empty(batch_size, dtype=torch.long).random_(num_classes)

output = criterion(logits, target)
loss = output * penalty_matrix[logits.max(dim=-1)[1], target]

loss.backward()
```